# How to add a style only to certain elements of a list via CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

Say I have this list:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="the_list">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

How can I apply a style, bottom border for example, only to the first two children of ul, without using JQuery, only CSS?

Comment: If your list is not being changed in the future, you could set up 2 classes for the two firsts `<li>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write something like,

```
.the_list li:nth-child(1),
.the_list li:nth-child(2) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid tomato;
}
```

So the above selector will select the first and the second child of your `ul` element with the `class` of `the_list`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wq3g4tu8/)

---

If you want to support vintage browsers like IE8, you can also do something like

```
.the_list li:first-child,
.the_list li:first-child + li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid tomato;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/wq3g4tu8/1/)

So here in the second selector, we are first selecting the first `li` element nested under `ul` with a `class` of `the_list` and then we select adjacent `li` to the first child.

Comment: `li:nth-child(-n+2)` is enough to select the first two children, no need for two selectors.

Comment: @maryisdead or that, there are many ways to do it, the one you suggested is one of them, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with one selector ...

```css
li:nth-of-type(-n+2){
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="the_list">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

... which will select the first two list items - this approach is better than using multiple selectors, because the list can potentially get very long.

Comment: I like that you use `-n+2`, but isn't `nth-child` sufficient?

Comment: @maryisdead force of habit really ... nth-child would definitely suffice, especially in a list, seeing that <li> is the only natural descendant.